# Wants to retrieve the date column alone from the table

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to retrieve the date column alone by using the below query but there is no result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE REQUESTED_DATE_TIME = '01-OCT-15';
```

Comment: What datatype is the REQUESTED_DATE_TIME column?

Answer (score 3):

Do not ever rely on implicit type conversion, especially not in cases where it depends on NLS settings.

```
select * from TABLE NAME where REQUESTED_DATE_TIME = to_date('01-OCT-15', 'DD-MON-YY');
```

Or even simpler, below syntax uses fixed date format:

```
select * from TABLE NAME where REQUESTED_DATE_TIME = date'2015-10-01';
```

Comment: Both queries are returned only blank result

Comment: @Iswariya We do not know your data. That may be the correct answer.

Comment: Agreed, additionally I think the OP might be trying to SELECT the date column on its own.  Something like SELECT REQUESTED_DATE_TIME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE... Instead of SELECT *

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use the `TO_DATE()` function. The first value of the function, you will enter the date in which ever format you want to use, the second value of the function, you are identifying the date format so Oracle knows how to read it.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE REQUESTED_DATE_TIME = to_date('10/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Also `SELECT *` will pull all columns from the "table_name" table. If you are trying to only pull the column REQUESTED_DATE_TIME then you will need to use

```
SELECT T.REQUESTED_DATE_TIME
FROM Table T
WHERE T.REQUESTED_DATE_TIME = to_date('10/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Answer (score 1):

`REQUESTED_DATE_TIME` seems to include a time portion and there's probably no row for '2015-10-01 00:00:00'.

Either truncate the column to a date:

```
select * from TABLE NAME 
where TRUNC(REQUESTED_DATE_TIME) = date'2015-10-01';
```

or compare using >/< (recommended because it might use an index):

```
select * from TABLE NAME 
where REQUESTED_DATE_TIME >= TIMESTAMP '2015-10-01 00:00:00'
  AND REQUESTED_DATE_TIME <  TIMESTAMP '2015-10-02 00:00:00';
```

@BalazsPapp already recommended you to use a date/timestamp literal instead of `TO_DATE` as there's only one valid format: `'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'`